# Overloading operator [] for both read and write

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm having a trouble overloading operator [] for both read and write in my objects. This is a large code with different components and I'm not going to put all the details here since it wont help. In a nutshell what I have is the following

```
class MyObject(){
    inline SetterProxy& operator[](int i) {
        SetterProxy a(i);
        return a;
    }
    inline double operator[](int i) const{            
        return some_value;
    }
}
```

The first overloaded [] works fine for assigning values (if you are wondering what the SetterProxy is, I have to use Proxy classes to be able to do some checking and internal function calls before assigning values). However, the second one which should supposedly be called when reading does not work and the code crashes. I'm not sure what is happening here but when I comment out the first one it just works fine! Could it be that compiler somehow confuses the two since they are both inline?

Any thought would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Ok here is the SetterProxy itself:

```
class SetterProxy{
private:
    Vec v;
    int i;
    double *ptr_val;
public:
    inline SetterProxy(Vec v_, int i_) {
        v = v_;
        i = i_;
        VecGetArray(v,&ptr_val);
    }
    inline ~SetterProxy(){
        VecRestoreArray(v,&ptr_val);
    }

    inline void operator=(double rhs ){
        ptr_val[i] = rhs;
    }
};
```

Although I dont think its coming directly from that. Also initially I had it to return by value and I though changing it to reference would be more efficient. I think this should be safe since the assignment is done in the Proxy operator=() class and after that the proxy class goes out of scope. Either way, that does not save my problem!

Comment: Could this be related to something you do inside `SetterProxy`? Could you please update the question with the digest of what it does?

Comment: Are you calling `operator[]` on a `const` object or a non-`const` object when it crashes?

Comment: @ seth: tried both const and non-const. The code crashes when calling something like `printf("%f\n",a[0]);`. Also using cout I get the compile error that the operator << is not defined for SetterProxy class! But the thing is isn't the compiler supposed to call the other overloaded [] ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're returning a reference to a local variable - it goes out of scope when the operator returns, leaving your reference dangling. A good compiler should warn you about this if you turn the warning setting up to a reasonable level.

Comment: Question: Isn't the code supposed to call the second operator when *reading* values in a printf statement for example?

Comment: @GradGuy : No, which overload is called is determined by the constness of the object, not by what you attempt to do with the return value. If your object isn't const, then the first overload will always be called.

Comment: Alright then. Is there anyway to ask the compiler call the second function for read-only purposes?

Comment: @GradGuy : Give it a unique name, or make your object const for the duration of the call. But in any case I don't see the point, because if the first overload is written properly there will be no harm in calling it even for read-only purposes.

Comment: @ildjarn: Well the problem is the first one uses a Proxy to set a value and thus what it returns has the type of a Proxy class and so the printf complains about it! I guess I have to write a new printf or overload << ?

Comment: @GradGuy : Using `printf` in C++ is already questionable because it lacks type safety. Overloading `operator<<` and using `std::cout` is the appropriate move.

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks for your help. Appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

As noted in @Stuart Golodetz's answer, you are returning a reference to `SetterProxy` referring to `a`, which is local to your method and thus goes out of scope when it returns.

You should instead return a `SetterProxy` instance *by value*: that shouldn't be a big deal, `SetterProxy` will probably just hold the index and a reference to the "parent" object, so the compiler-generated copy constructor for it will be fine and the copy won't be costly at all.

By the way, unless you want to allow negative indexes, the usual idiom is to use `size_t` for indexes in arrays.

Comment: As an aside, is it ever better in practice to use `size_t` instead of `unsigned int` (or if it is always better, why)?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: `unsigned int` isn't guaranteed to be big enough to hold the size of any object that can be allocated (and thus indexes inside them); think about Windows x86_64: `unsigned int` is 32 bit, while `size_t` is 64 bit (so `unsigned int` cannot be used as index for >4GB arrays - which can exist there, while `size_t` can). Have a look [here](http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/programming-pointers/4026076/Why-size-t-matters) for other examples.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: use `ptrdiff_t`, because it's signed (avoiding trouble) and large enough. use `size_t` if you're programming for certain old-fashioned DSPs, or if you're willing to accept various bugs and general trouble for the sake of appearing to conform with general public opinion, and/or for the sake of appearing to conform with the standard library's convention (which supports archaic systems that now don't exist anymore). Needless to say the "appearing to conform" reasons are technically unsound. But sometimes its better to sacrifice on the technical, especially with a primitive manager.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach so on a 32 bit system `ptrdiff_t` would be over 32 bits?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Since you're asking you probably think that you already know the answer to that, which, if true, means that the question is not entirely honest, and designed to deceive. :-( But anyway, the range issue is a concern on 16-bit systems. Whence the C standard requires `ptrdiff_t` to be at least 17 bits. Now I bet you didn't know *that*. A little knowledge is dangerous, as they say.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach no, it was a genuine question, I wasn't trying to deceive you, sorry you thought that. So by your answer, I think the answer to my question is yes, right? I can't really tell from your reply because it seems to be talking about 16 bit systems.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach Hanlon's razor: Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity.

Comment: @drhirsch precisely, thank you. And I still have no idea why you thought I was trying to deceive you Alf, English is not my first language so I might have implied something accidentally. Please let me know so I don't do it again.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: it's possible to construct a greater than 2GB array of `char` in non-Windows 32-bit system, or with Windows specially configured to allow 3GB application address space. In this special case a 32-bit `ptrdiff_t` doesn't cut it. Implementations still define it as 32-bit, and the standard then makes the cases where it's not good enough, Undefined Behavior. That's very reasonable, because one Very Seldom™ needs a greater than 2 GB array of `char` in a 32-bit system. I have never needed it. Nobody I know have ever needed it.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach so then the advantage is that it is signed I assume. Thanks, I won't take any more of your time.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach : It seems to me that despite your rant you're still saying that `size_t` is the only type guaranteed to be large enough, so why exactly are you advocating `ptrdiff_t`? What advantage is being signed if the type is insufficient otherwise?

Comment: @ildjarn: it's a tradeoff: `ptrdiff_t` is "informally" the signed counterpart of `size_t`, so you are still getting a type of the right order of magnitude, but avoiding the pitfalls of using `unsigned` types. On the other hand, if you have an object bigger than half your address space (on typical implementations) you won't be able to store its size/index it using `ptrdiff_t`. As for the fact that `ptrdiff_t` can hold negative values, this can be an advantage (to allow negative offsets, to have "special" values, ...) or another thing to `assert`. It's your choice.

Comment: @ildjarn: No i haven't said that. But if you want an accurate statement of what's large enough for what, `ptrdiff_t` is only large enough for *the well-defined cases*, which include all that's used in practice, while `size_t` is large enough also for the generally UB case that nobody needs. Note that the result of pointer subtraction is formally `ptrdiff_t`. Thus, in a case where `ptrdiff_t` doesn't cut it (which due to the C standard's requirements implies 32-bit system or higher) you're generally already in UB-land. Thus, considerations of range are irrelevant here. It's Good Enough.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach, @Matteo : Ah, I see now. I wasn't seeing where UB came into play, but that was an oversight on my part. Thanks for the explanations. (FWIW, before x64 became ubiquitous, I did many server applications that relied on Win32's /3GB switch, so the case where `size_t` is needed doesn't seem all that foreign to me; that `ptrdiff_t` was lacking in that scenario somehow never occurred to me.)

Comment: @Seth: "And I still have no idea why you thought I was trying to deceive" Well you first asked why `size_t` could be preferable to `unsigned int`, indicating unawareness of range issues. Then you asked about the special 3GB array of `char` case, which indicates not only intimate familiarity with the range issues, but also with that specific question's common usage as a diversionary thing (noise generator). I found that a bit inconsistent. However, one can never be sure about such things. I just say what's on my mind, what I think, then people can correct my impression if/when it's wrong...

Comment: Just to add a "me too" to this - I've also found a need to use the /3GB switch in the past when doing medical imaging. To what extent that makes it less uncommon, who knows :)

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach I was really meaning to ask "when is `size_t` not simply a `typedef` of `unsigned it`" because I have never seen a situation where it was not. I was aware of range issues only up to what common sense could provide you. I asked about "the special 3GB array of `char` case" (which, until just now, I didn't know had a name or was special) because it seemed to be a problem with using a signed type of the same # of bits as the unsigned type that is just barely able to index everything. I was only analysing your comment, I have had no previous knowledge of `ptrdiff_t` ever, and

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach especially not its use as "flame-bait" (if I understand what you mean, that's what it is used as.) My entire knowledge of this whole `ptrdiff_t` thing is only what you've told me and what I can get by common sense. So yes, it was ignorance and definitely not malice, and your impression was wrong. And in fact if I look back now, you said that `ptrdiff_t` is "big enough", which does imply a "for most cases". So I wasn't trying to trick you at all, and I say this over and over because I don't want you to think I'm a malicious person. Thank you for expanding my knowledge.

Comment: @Seth: i'm sorry. i misunderstood a coincidence.

Comment: @Alf yes that is the perfect word for it that I was searching for, "coincidence". No need to apologise, I'm just glad I was able to communicate my intentions even if it was only after some explanation. I will be more careful in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: Interesting discussion spun off here :-) To add my two cent: Even if you found the need to use the /3GB switch in windows, you are still very likely absolutely fine with using ptrdiff_t . The only case I am aware of is where it doesn't suffice is if you compare two indices in an array of _char_ which is bigger than _2 GB_. If you have a larger base type, it doesn't matter - the indices will not be big enough to make a difference between ptrdiff_t and size_t. So Alf is perfectly right, this case is not relevant in practice.

Comment: @drhirsch : In my experience, the only practical reason to use /3GB is when you _do_ need contiguous allocations over 2GB in size.

Comment: Yes, but are they really of type char and do you use the index in a comparison? For example a `int big[0x28000000]` will use 2.5 GB memory, but it can be used with a `ptrdiff_t` type index without problems

Comment: @MatteoItalia: IMHO, the primary reason `int` is 32 bits on x64 systems is because C lacks any means of distinguishing unsigned-int values which should promote and those which shouldn't, and a lot of code will break of `uint32_t` values get promoted to `int64`.  IMHO, the proper remedy would be to add a means of declaring "I want something to perform arithmetic mod 2^32" versus "I only want to spend 32 bits for something to hold positive numbers, but would be happy if it promoted on systems where `int` is larger".  IMHO, C really needs such types to avoid being stuck in a 32-bit world.